# How to save ffmpeg output.mp4 to file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a very basic question. I combined an .wav and .mp4 file to output.mp4 using ffmpeg in python:

```
   !ffmpeg -i /content/input.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Now how do I save the output.mp4 to an .mp4 file on my computer?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What is the `!` at the beginning of the code line? In case there are no errors, then `output.mp4` is going to be saved as file in your working directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For executing `ffmpeg` withing Python, you may use `subprocess`:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.run('ffmpeg -y -i /content/input.mp4 -i audio.wav -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4')
```

Test the conversion in `ffmpeg` command line (in console) before using Python and verify there are no errors.

In most cases you can't keep the audio codec (using `-c:a copy`) with `.wav` file as input, and store result into `.mp4` video file.

I am getting the following error message:

> [mp4 @ 000001d150ea6780] Could not find tag for codec pcm_s16le in stream #1, codec not currently supported in container
>   Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

In case of an error, use: `-c:a aac`.

Using `-c:a copy` works when the codec of the `wav` file is ac3 for example (but it's a rare case).

---

Testing the solution by generating synthetic audio and video input files:

```
import subprocess as sp

sp.run('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=30 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 input1.mp4')
sp.run('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -acodec ac3 -ar 22050 -t 5 audio1.wav')
sp.run('ffmpeg -y -i input1.mp4 -i audio1.wav -c:v copy -c:a copy output1.mp4')
```

The above code is working because I selected `ac3` codec for `audio1.wav`.